# How to use an environment variable in a route in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I can make environment variables accessible to the app locally with a `.env` file

Problem is, I can't work out how to use the variable in a route

I have tried variations of

```
get 'v1/packages<%= ENV["key1"] %>' => 'flatfiles#raw'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work (the browser says no route matches, but I can also tell from running `rake routes` which gives

```
GET  /v1/packages%3C%25=%20ENV[%22key1%22]%20%25%3E(.:format)
```

I also tried

```
get 'v1/packages#{ENV["key1"]}' => 'flatfiles#raw'
```

which makes the route

```
GET  /v1/packages%23%7BENV[%22key1%22]%7D
```

Neither method seems to insert the 'key1' variable into the route as I hope to do

For good measure, I also tried creating a `Key` model, and accessed it that way, but the route still interprets the variable literally

```
  @key1 = Key.find(1).private_key
  get 'v1/packages#{@key1}'  => 'flatfiles#raw'
```

```
GET /v1/packages_and_functions%23%7B@key1%7D
```

Comment: `<%= ... %>` is ERB only works in places that support ERB (i.e. not in arbitrary Ruby source files like `routes.rb`). `#{...}` string interpolation doesn't work in single quote strings, you want double quoted strings for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your mistake is to try using format strings within a single quoted string:

```rb
get 'v1/packages#{ENV["key1"]}' => 'flatfiles#raw'
```

which means that the string is being taken as is. You shall be using double quotes instead, so that ruby can understand that you actually want a format within a string:

```rb
get "v1/packages#{ENV['key1']}" => 'flatfiles#raw'
```

If your editor has a proper support of syntax coloration, you'd notice that the former one would appear as a single color, whereas the second one will have the format part (`#{}`) highlighted.

Finally, the `<%= ... %>` syntax is only used within ERB templates, that Rails processes for you when you edit some `.yml` or `html.erb` files, or explicitely using `ERB.new(...)` within your code.

HTH